# Slowly 1050ti mining

Tags: mining, hash, hashrate, nvidia

I have a 1050ti GPU and my hash rate is so slow around: `2.03 Mh/s`.

[image]

Other people using the same GPU are making `14 Mh/s`.

My OS is Windows 10 and I'm using Claymore to mine.

*What can I do to increase the hash rate?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing SOLO mining, join a pool, there are several mining pools available and you can find the list here: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3659/list-of-pools

Also if you are really into having profit, Set up a mining rig with 4 to 6 GPUs.
Thank you

edit: If possible let me know the full specs of your GPU 1050 ti

Comment: My space: motherboard asus xi hero, CPU i7700k and GPU gtx 1050ti

Answer (score 0):

Change your NVida control panel settings. To optimize for compute performance to on, and your DSR factors to 2x